# curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application in appcenter

Tags: bash, curl, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to upload `app-release.apk` file from https://appcenter.ms/ to s3 bucket using `curl` command through `appcenter post-build` script but getting this error `curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application`

here is my complete `post-build` script

File_name: `appcenter-post-build.sh`

```
if [ "$AGENT_JOBSTATUS" == "Succeeded" ]; then

    # Example: Upload main branch app binary to HockeyApp using the API
    echo "Current branch is $APPCENTER_BRANCH"
    if [ "$APPCENTER_BRANCH" == "staging" ];
     then
        curl \
        -F "status=2" \
        -F "file_stage=@$APPCENTER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/app-release.apk" \
        https://stag.api.website.com/v1/upload/android
        # curl --location 'https://stag.api.website.com/v1/upload/android' \
        # --form 'file_stage=@"$APPCENTER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/app-release.apk"'
    else
        echo "Current branch is $APPCENTER_BRANCH"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by replace the file path name from `$APPCENTER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/app-release.apk` to `/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`

My final working codes are

```
if [ "$AGENT_JOBSTATUS" == "Succeeded" ]; then

    # Example: Upload main branch app binary to HockeyApp using the API
    echo "Current branch is $APPCENTER_BRANCH"
    if [ "$APPCENTER_BRANCH" == "staging" ];
     then
        curl \
        -F "status=2" \
        -F "file_stage=@/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk" \
        -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
        https://stag.api.website.com/v1/upload/android
    else
        echo "Current branch is $APPCENTER_BRANCH"
    fi
fi
```